# Jquery PopUp plugin - can we modify it

Tags: jquery

I have a text area in my form, but user wants the ability to open a larger 'box' to view or edit the data. I thought jquery pop up plugin might be useful which i is given at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/popBox

In the demo given in the above link, the original text area is non editable and on click of that text area, new pop up editor opens to read/edit the data, instead I am looking for keeping the original text area editable and a image link next to it and on click of it pop up the editor to read/edit the text with done and cancel buttons , the changed text should be reflectd in the original text area, is that possible with popup plug in modification or suggest me any good pop up editor code I can use.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/) fits your need - specifically example 9.

Comment: that may not be useful to me as I am looking for pop up text area, not the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [jQuery Tools Overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html) in a few projects. I think it fits your requirements very nicely and would recommend giving it a try.

To illustrate how you can use it to solve your problem, I created a [simple demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BVww/36/).

It works by defining an (HTML) form that will become the "popup" dialog. The form contains a textarea and ok/cancel buttons. When edit button is clicked ("show me extended editor"), jQuery Tools "overlay()" function is used to display the popup (centered on page). Rest of the solution is transferring values between the original and extended input controls and managing keyboard focus.